# Having Highcharts render bar/column charts with multiple colors by default

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I know there's a lot of questions out there about setting the color of the bars on certain Highcharts, but my question is a bit different.  By default on the Highcharts site, all the lines on a bar/column chart are a different color.  When I try to implement a bar/column chart on my site, all the lines are the same color.  I've looked at the fiddles on Highcharts demo section, and nothing in there is defining that each bar be a different color.  If I use a pie chart on my site, all the sections are a different color, but I cannot get my bar/columns to follow suit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues here...

(1) *"By default on the Highcharts site, all the lines on a bar/column chart
are a different color."*
This is not true. The opening page of the highcharts website has a column chart, and all the columns have the same color. http://www.highcharts.com/

(2) When you implement a bar chart on your site, do you have just one `series` or multiple objects in your `series`? My guess is you have just one object in your `series`, in which case it makes sense that the *one* `series` would be coded in just *one* color by highcharts.

(3) Open one of the highcharts examples in jsfiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/

Change the data so that this:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 1900',
        data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 2008',
        data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
    }]
```

...is reduced to this:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
    }]
```

You should only see one bar color here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You are correct, the opening chart does.  I was talking about the bar/column charts on the demos page.  

As for my site, I have multiple objects in an array as my series.  So: 

[{name: "Blah", data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, {name: "Blah2", data: [5,4,3,2,1]}]

And yet any time I add a new series, it's rendered in a default blue.  I have added 4 or 5 series, all render blue.

Any other ideas?

Comment: @Siraris - posting a fiddle with your code or a streamlined version of your code/output would probably help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LX7az/

_dataArray is an array of objects in the format I posted previously, categoryArray is an array of names.

Comment: this is what I see:  http://i.imgur.com/iyi7oJK.png if I add 4 data objects to data array.  I WANT each line to be a different color. Data is formatted as 

[{name: "Rep", [34, 30, 64, 15, 9, 88, 5, 93, 1, 1, 2, 3]}, {name: "Test", [33, 27, 60, 8, 8, 76, 4, 80, 3, 3, 8, 8]}... etc]

The only thing I noticed is that if I inspect the array in Chrome, it shows a property _colorIndex of 0 on all the objects that I am not setting.  Could that be effecting it? Otherwise it makes no sense based on the demos, and your fiddles.

Comment: So I added _colorIndex:0 to your fiddle on each series object,  and that seems to be causing the lines to all be the same color.  Is there a way to disable this behavior?  I am not setting it in my code anywhere.

Comment: @Siriaris - you posted a fiddle, but it was not a fully functional fiddle with the variables for the data substituted with real values. That's the type of replica that would be helpful for debugging your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your chart constructor:

```
colors: ['#0D233A', '#2F7ED8', '#AAAAAA'],
plotOptions: {
    series: {
    colorByPoint: true
    }
},
```

For each series it will go through your colors list and color each bar/column in order and repeat from the beginning if it reaches the end of the list.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctb3/AQcmF/)

Answer (score 0):

Each series has own `color`, like in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/z5sGy/

But you can use colors to define your own order: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors

In case when you would like to modify colors for each data point, you can define this parametr for data.

http://jsfiddle.net/z5sGy/1/